# typedef of array of typedefs of array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, typedef

As the title might look very confusing, let me give you an example:

```
typedef bool foo[2];
typedef foo bar[4];
bar what_am_i;
```

So, is `what_am_i` a `[4][2]` dimensional array as I presume, or a `[2][4]` dimensional array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspecting the variable through the debugger, I found that I was right - `what_am_i` is a `[4][2]` dimensional array.

Answer (score 21):

It's `bool[4][2]`
You can verify it by static_assert:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(what_am_i), bool[4][2]>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(what_am_i), bool[2][4]>::value, ""); // failed
```

Answer (score 13):

`foo` is an array with `2` elements of type `bool`, i.e. `bool[2]`.

`bar` is an array with **`4`** elements of type `foo`, i.e. `foo[4]`, each element is a `bool[2]`.

Then `what_am_i` is `bool[4][2]`.

Answer (score 6):

In order to complete @Slardar Zhang's C++ answer for C:

It's `bool[4][2]`.

You can verify it by either one of the following:

- `sizeof(what_am_i)/sizeof(*what_am_i) == 4`
- `sizeof(*what_am_i)/sizeof(**what_am_i) == 2`

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know the type of a variable, one of the easy ways is this trick:

```
 template<class T> struct tag_type{using type=T;};
 template<class T> constexpr tag_type<T> tag{};
```

then do this:

```
 tag_type<void> t = tag<some_type>;
```

almost every compiler will spit out a reasonably readable "you cannot assign `tag_type<full_unpacked_type>` to `tag_type<void>`" or somesuch (presuming your type isn't `void` that is).

You can also verify you have a good guess with

```
tag_type<your_guess> t = tag<some_type>;
```

sometimes you'll want to generate `some_type` via `decltype(some_expression)`.

Comment: or you can `cout << typeid(what_am_i).name()`—after piping through c++filt, it reports `bool [4][2]`.